# Ajax in Prestahop module

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, prestashop-1.6

I have problem with ajax response in prestahop.

I wrote module with method

cheaperproduct.php

```
public function GetData(){
         if(Tools::getValue('method')) echo "asdasd";
         echo "string";
}
```

and in main.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cheaper form').submit(function(){
        var url = $("#cheaper .url").val();
        var email = $("#cheaper .email").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: baseDir+'modules/cheaperproduct/cheaperproduct.php',
            method:"post",
            data:'method=GetData',
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        })
        return false;
    })
})
```

And I have empty alert.

I checked many ways to resolve my problem, but no one help me.

Can somebody explain me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
try this:

public function GetData(){
    if(Tools::getValue('method')) die(json_encode('ciao'));;
        echo "method not found!";
}
```